# add different elements in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, element

**My previous question was:**
Hide listview on click
hi all, i want to hide a listview on a click of a button. i have a mainactivity.in which there are 2 listviews.

and my mainactivity extends Activity which can't be used by implements keyword.. and for hiding listview your activity must extends listactivity. as in below code..

but android donot use multiple inheritance. so how it could be done?

```
Use getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); within your ListActivity.

This is how it looks inside your code:

public OnClickListener teamlisten = new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
};
```

**It works and now my 2nd question is:**
how to add different elements in a `listview`?
like my first row elemnt will be a profile image.
and rest will be text like home, profile, settings etc.

Comment: Why post your previous question here, that's not use. You should really do some basic tutorials first, Java and Android. Have a look here ...http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html. If you got some concrete programming problems, you can come back.

Comment: create a customized adapter to add different elements

Comment: please give solution with code.

Answer (score 0):

refer this code to hide list view :

```
 String a1[] =new String[]{"Apple","Mango"};
    String a2[] =new String[]{"shop","mall"};
    print=(Button)findViewById(R.id.click);

    l1  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a1);
    l1.setAdapter(adapter);

    l2  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a2);
    l2.setAdapter(adapter1);
    print.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {               
            l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

2 Answer : Use Custom Adapter class and define there imageview or textview as per your requirement and put that adapter class in your list view...

Answer (score 0):

2 Answer: To put different items in a list view what you can do is 
1. make different models like : Profile, Settings etc and extend them to a single Base class say: BaseModel.
2.Populate your listview using a arraylist of type basemodel and put differnt items like Profile, Settings etc.
3. In getView iterate through the list and put checks of instanceof operator and perform different actions. 
This is how i did for 3 types of item in a listview.

Any kind of feedback is appreciated.

Comment: sorry i don't know more about custom adapter.. but i tried it. but not working i am posting my code in answer .. then tell me what is the problem..

Comment: Are you adding a navigation drawer with different items in it ?